# How to create a swipe animation in blackberry cascades QML

Tags: animation, blackberry, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have a listview which has a customlist component and this component has two view inside (swipeleftview and swiperightview). I have implemented the swipe handler that shows these views correctly based on swipe left and right. Currently on my swipe gesture I have hidden the other view, ie while swiping left I hide the right view and show the left view and vice versa. Now instead of hiding I need them to animate like while swiping left the swipeleftview should animate to left and at the same time swiperightview should animate to its current position and vice versa. I have checked out some animations described in cookbook but cant seem to make it work properly. Below is a code structure of my listview and its item that I created

```
  ListView {
                    id: contactListView
                    dataModel: contactsData
                    listItemComponents: [
                        ListItemComponent {
                            id: homeListComponent
                            type: "item"
                            CustomListItemHomePage { //some code to display items }
                                }]
            }
```

CustomListItemHomePage is a container that has swipeleft and swiperight views

Comment: You could use a ListView with horizontal scrolling instead.